# Can bulls be slaughtered by nahr (stabbing) for qurbani?

Tags: dhabihah, sacrifice

I see that people often have difficulty restraining bulls for sacrifice because they are so powerful and foul tempered. Is it permitted to slaughter them by nahr similar to how camels are slaughtered?